# Glassfish JSF Jars

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish, glassfish-3

I downloaded the zip version of Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and unzip it in my local directory.

When I try to add the following glassfish directory as a runtime library, it says there is no glassfish runtime.

I checked out the folder and I think it is missing some jsf jar such as jsf-impl..

How do I set this up? DO I really need to download some 3rd party jsf implmentation jars?

Thanks

Comment: What platform are you on?  Installing GlassFish should involve more than just "_unzipping_" a zip file.  There should be some kind of installer.  GlassFish 3.1 should be able to run JSF 2 out of the box.

Comment: Its windows....and its not the installer...it is the zip version..

Comment: @jahroy: the installer only allows you to configure admin password and the port numbers by GUI instead of afterwards in command console (and also a way to "uninstall" it). This is not relevant to get Glassfish to run anyway. Unziupping is certainly sufficient. Mark, your question is vague. Are you talking about integrating Glassfish in Eclipse? If so, how exactly are you trying to do that? It should indeed just be a matter of unzipping and then adding it as *New Server* (make sure that you've the proper GF Eclipse plugin and are really seeing "GlassFish 3.1.2.2" option in the servers list).

Comment: @BalusC, no actually I was just wondering why I cant find the JSF jars in the glassfish module directory...I was looking for the jsf-impl.jar etc.... Does this mean, I really need to download the MOjarra jars?  About the eclipse, I was just trying to install the server runtime and pointing it to that directory but eclipse always says, it is not a valid glassfish directory

Comment: Uh OK. It's the `javax.faces.jar` file. It's renamed since Mojarra 2.1.6. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145868/libraries-for-jsf-sun-oracle-mojarra/11150263#11150263 Is that really all what you're asking?

Comment: @BalusC, exactly the information I need.  I got really confused with how JSF is evolving. Thanks for the guidance.. You can delete this thread or tagged it as duplicate of the other..

Comment: Just to be sure before posting the answer. I wouldn't like to post incomplete answers :)

Comment: @balusc the windows installer also include the helper program for registering as a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I checked out the folder and I think it is missing some jsf jar such as jsf-impl.*

The two JARs `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` have since Mojarra 2.1.6 been merged into a single JAR `javax.faces.jar`. This was done so to be in line with general Java EE Maven rules. See also [issue 2028](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2028).

Comment: Oh and a nice Santa Hat! Merry Holiday Season!